# Align row based on sibling in foundation grid

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I'm using foundation grid for sites, and would want to accomplish a following scenario:

```
<row>content</row>
<row>content_2</row>
```

I would want that the first row is centered (which I have been able to do). But then the second row would not be centered, but instead it would align according to the first row. I would want the second row to align to the left of the first row. So that the content of the rows would begin in the same place horizontally.

The content of the first row is dynamic (depending on language, fonts etc), so I do not know the width of it. I would want the second row to align according to it in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this style:

```
row {
display:inline-block;
}
```

**UPD**
I tested on this code:

```
<div class="outer">
  <row>row1</row>
  <row>row1</row>
</div>
```

style:

```
row
{
  display:inline-block;
}

.outer
{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Adding it disabled centering :/

Comment: using foundation grid attribute small-centered

Comment: Thanks for trying! Unfortunately your update did not work because it only centers text. I actually found a solution, I might post it here if I have time.